# sqlite3 vacuum command and referenced rowid

Tags: sqlite

suppose I have a database like:

CREATE TABLE top_table (
test_id PRIMARY KEY,
cmd TEXT);

CREATE TABLE job_table (
id PRIMARY KEY,
rid integer references top_table(rowid));

If I do a vacuum, would it preserve the relationship "rid integer references top_table(rowid)"? Meaning, would it either leave the top_table rowids unchanged, or would it change them and make corresponding changes to rid in job_table? I want to do the vacuum because I'm merging databases, so I read in a second table, insert its data into an existing table, and drop the second table. If the vacuum won't work properly, my next thought was to create the combined database, drop the table, do a sump and read the sql into a new database. Or is there an easier/cleaner method that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Why would it *not* preserve the relationship? It is not going to change any of your data.

Comment: I was under the impression that vacuum doesn't change any values except for rowids, but does change those.

Comment: Ah, hmm, you're right. The question is why you used foreign keys referencing the rowid? I thought this was strictly prohibited. See https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html - "The parent key is the column or set of columns in the parent table that the foreign key constraint refers to. This is normally, but not always, the primary key of the parent table. The parent key must be a named column or columns in the parent table, **not the rowid**."

Comment: I'm somewhat new at this, but strictly speaking, am I using foreign keys? I'm not declaring it to be a foreign key, and "pragma foreign_keys" returns 0

Comment: The rowids may be changed. The source of your problem is the design of the tables. Is there a reason that you did not define `test_id` as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, `id` as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` and `rid` as `INTEGER REFERENCES top_table(test_id)`?

Comment: test_id is a string, which can be relatively long (60-80 characters or so). the original version of the schema had test_id as a member of both tables. the version that I've shown above (with a bunch of fields removed from both tables for this question) was a check on how much smaller the database got if I switched matching long text strings to matching the rowid which seemed to make more sense than adding a field that serves the same purpose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using :-

```
CREATE TABLE top_table ( test_id PRIMARY KEY, cmd TEXT);
CREATE TABLE job_table ( id PRIMARY KEY, rid integer references top_table(rowid));
```

Could be an issue as you are referencing the rowid directly rather than referencing an alias of the rowid. Typically an alias of the rowid would be used as per :-

```
CREATE TABLE top_table ( test_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, cmd TEXT);
CREATE TABLE job_table ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, rid INTEGER REFERENCES top_table(test_id));
```

That is specifying `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, instead of `PRIMARY KEY` (column affinity NUMERIC) is a **special case which makes the column being defined an alias of the rowid**, the rowid will then not be subject to change by the VACUUM command as per :-

- *The VACUUM command may change the ROWIDs of entries in any tables that do not have an explicit INTEGER PRIMARY KEY.*
- [SQLITE -CREATE TABLE - ROWID's and the INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)
- [SQLite - VACUUM](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html)

> I'm somewhat new at this, but strictly speaking, am I using foreign keys? I'm not declaring it to be a foreign key, and "pragma foreign_keys" returns 0

No BUT only because Foreign KEY enforcement is off (hasn't been turned on), thus the `REFERENCES top_table(test_id)` has no effect, other than being parsed.

Assuming that you programmatically maintain the referential integrity this should not be an issue.

It can be advantageous to have FOREIGN KEY support on as not only will referential integrity be enforced, the ON UPDATE and ON DELETE actions can then be utilised which can simplify handling updates and deletions by using the CASCADE option *(e.g. deleting a parent will **a)** work without a conflict and **b)** cascade the deletion so that the children rows will be deleted automatically (if they can be))*

- [SQLite - Enabling Foreign Key Support](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable)
- [SQLite - ON DELETE and ON UPDATE Actions](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_actions)

**regarding the comment**

> test_id is a string, which can be relatively long (60-80 characters or so). the original version of the schema had test_id as a member of both tables. the version that I've shown above (with a bunch of fields removed from both tables for this question) was a check on how much smaller the database got if I switched matching long text strings to matching the rowid which seemed to make more sense than adding a field that serves the same purpose)

In the case where a string is used for referencing will not only save space (in the longer term) BUT the overheads will also be greater than using an alias of the rowid.

- In the longer term, because SQLite save chunks (pages). A table will (by default) takes up at least 4k and then 8k ....

First, space wise, not only will the extra 52-80 bytes waste space the parent's column should also be unique. If UNIQUE were specified then there is the additional overhead of an index.

However, with an alias of the rowid, then 8 bytes max for the integer, which is used anyway unless the table is defined using WITHOUT ROWID. If I recall there is an extra byte for the flag that the column is an alias of the rowid. The rowid and therefore alias has to be unique and the index (as such) exists. Furthermore due to it being central to SQLite accessing by rowid can be twice as fast.

**In short an alias of the rowid is probably the best option in many (probably most) cases for relationships.**

Comment: I'm somewhat new at this, but strictly speaking, am I using foreign keys? I'm not declaring it to be a foreign key, and "pragma foreign_keys" returns 0

No BUT only because Foreign KEY enforcement is off (hasn't been turned on), thus the REFERENCES top_table(test_id) has no effect, other than being parsed.

Haha, really shot myself in the foot with that one. Sounds like my best bet is to either have the long text string in two tables or have it once in one table but add an integer field to one and an integer/foreign key to the other. Which is probably smaller in the long run.

Comment: So my original tables had long(ish) character strings as primary keys (seemed like a good idea, because they're unique). Switching to integers for primary keys and referencing those keys in the other tables saved me ~1/3 on the database size.